# Приложение на .net 4.6.1 не запускается на некоторых ПК из-за MEF. Проект Gemini

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mef

Я использую System.ComponentModel.Composition и атрибуты [Export] в своем проекте чистая 4.6.1.
Также есть сторонний проект, который отвечает за интерфейс - Gemini (netcore3;.net461).
На моем пк и 95% пользователей все хорошо, но у некоторых, программа работает просто нестабильно, такое ощущение, что некоторые Export просто не срабатывают.

Путем отлова ошибок, выяснилось следующее:
У меня есть статический класс где я определяю элемент Меню

```
[Export]
public static MenuDefinition MainToolsMenu = new MenuDefinition(Gemini.Modules.MainMenu.MenuDefinitions.MainMenuBar, 2, Resources.Menu);
```

в проекте Gemini также есть статический класс, где определяется

```
[Export]
public static MenuBarDefinition MainMenuBar = new MenuBarDefinition();
```

Вот в своем проекте, я ссылаюсь на MainMenuBar, но там Null. И это происходит только на некоторых ПК. Я проверял тысячу раз на своем ПК и порядок выполнения кода был нормальный. Сначала MainMenuBar из dll, а потом MainToolsMenu из моего основного проекта. Поэтому конфликта нет.

Почему может такое происходить и куда копать?
Это только вершина проблемы. Я пытался убирать ссылки, просто не использовать Меню, но тогда проблемы возникают в других частях проекта, везде где я ссылаюсь на проект Gemini или его производных, исполняющий файл говорит, что он просто не может найти эти dll.

Comment: Нужные версии фреймворков установлены на машинах?

Comment: У меня есть подозрение, что 1) сторонний компонент регистрируется в GAC 2) Но вы его не ставили на все машины, поэтому не везде он там есть. Тогда такая каритна и была бы: есть зависимость. На машинах разработчика эта зависимость есть, на пользовательских машинах - скоре всего, нет.

Comment: да, стоит 4.8, в какой-то момент экспериментов получилось сделать так, что приложение запустилось, но как-будто только сторонние проекты, а основная программа вся не прочиталась, многие экспорты не сработали

Comment: А загруженные сборки (assembly) одинаковые на машине разработчика и на машине где воспроизводится баг?

Comment: Ну вообще-то 4.8 и 4.6.1 - это весьма разные фреймворки. Я помню при переезде с 4.7 на 4.8 или какой-то подобной версии сталкивался с тем, что не было функции какой-то простой функции типа string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (не конкретно её, но какой-то простой синтаксический сахар). У вас-то стоит студия, полный набор всех фреймворков, а на целевой машине? Либо попробуйте у себя поднять версию проекта до 4.8 (и может даже перестанет компилиться, не то, что в рантайме свалится), либо на целевой машине ставьте 4.6.1

Comment: Все проблемные проекты находятся в одном Солюшене, сторонние проекты не регистрируются в GAC. Пока проблемных пк всего 2 из 20 и их объединяет .net 4.8

Comment: Загруженные сборки в вижуал студии: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4921598/5752652

Comment: В выводе обнаружил такое, это может быть причиной? System.ComponentModel.Composition Warning: 3 : Каталогу "DirectoryCatalog (Path="./")" не удалось загрузить сборку "<->\DEBUG\EVRPRESENTER32.DLL". Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "EVRPRESENTER32.DLL" либо одну из их зависимостей. Ожидалось, что модуль содержит манифест сборки.

Comment: также связанное с это dll: "DungeonMate.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: DungeonMate.exe). Загружено "C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.Composition\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll". Загрузка символов пропущена. Модуль оптимизирован, включен параметр отладчика "Только мой код".